# Unable to serve image (png) with node.js and express

Tags: node.js

I've studied similar questions on SO but haven't found a solution to my problem... I've set up an express route to serve images but I can't get it to return an image from where it's stored.  Notice I've included a statement to allow requests from any origin. What happens is that when I make a request to `http://localhost:8080/images/x10.png` the response I get is an empty image element with `src="http://localhost:8080/images/x10.png` instead of from `http://ubuntubox.dev/images/x10.png`, which is where the image is actually located and is the path I'm ultimately passing to the request method. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
app.get('/images/*', function(req, res, path){
  var imagePath = req.url,
      url = 'http://ubuntubox.dev' + imagePath;

  request(url, function(error, response, img) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
      res.end(img, 'binary');
    } else if(response.statusCode === 404) {
      res.status(404);
      res.type('txt').send('oops');
    }
  });
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with `request()`. Is that `http.request()` (if it is, it needs to be fixed) or is a custom function you've defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you still have this problem, but..

The solution for your problem is just putting a .pipe(res) and it will send the file to the response

```
app.get('/images/*', function(req, res, path){
  var imagePath = req.url,
      url = 'http://ubuntubox.dev' + imagePath;

  request(url).pipe(res);
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: not exactly working, but it's more elegant than my solution.. a few tweaks and it worked



`app.get('/images/*', function(req, res){
 var imgpth = req.url,
 img = root_path + imgpth;

 res.sendFile(img);

});`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to serve images and other assets in a way that makes sense and doesn't require you to write a million routes, try this:

1. Create a new folder "public" and move all of your assets into it.
2. Open server.js and add the following line:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

Your assets should now be available like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

Soure: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's the same case or not.

But here is my answer:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var dir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.use('/public', express.static(dir));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Notice this line:

> app.use('/public', express.static(dir));

You need to add the path again with the `app.use` method
I don't get the idea of adding this part, but it was the only way to make it works.
and without it keeps responding 'Error' and I can not access this file.

hopefully, I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out for myself in express 4

```
app.get('/images/img1.png', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('/Absolute/path/to/the/file/images/img1.png');
});
```

Comment: This is not useful iguess.. you can not write a route for each image.. like img1.. img2.. and so on and send that file in response

Answer (score 0):

[user2879041](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2879041/user2879041) has already answered what he found useful, still I would think of another way for serving images, (where I shall not write a route for each file manually and the send the file to the browser).

As you are already using express, just server tyhe static images directly, you have already got that in `express.static`

```
app.use(express.static('/Absolute/path/to/the/file/images/img1.png'));
```

**benefit** of using express.static is that you would just keep adding the images inside the folder you want to be static and express will serve the images for you(no need to add any code).

Comment: It's not working form me unfortunately. Seems like it would be almost the same as my implementation anyway.

I'm getting a 404 and it's in the correct location with the correct name.


'Cannot GET /images/the_image.png'